# Service restart mechanism in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I'm looking for an explanation on how chef's restart mechanism works behind the scenes. I can't find any documentation for it online, and I got stuck trying to trace the code (triggers are spooky action-at-a-distance).

Let's look specifically at `nginx`, and assume we're using a chef server and not `chef-solo` (I don't know if that makes  a difference).

I have this (for example) in a recipe:

```
template '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' do
  source 'nginx.cfg.erb'
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00755
  notifies :reload, "service[nginx]", :delayed
end
```

The `notifies :reload` bit means it triggers a reload, and the `:delayed` means that it will happen at the end of the `chef-client` run. How does that work behind the scenes? I'm having trouble following the execution thread.

Somewhere `chef-client` has to run `service nginx reload` or something along those lines. Where and how is that defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`notifies` sends a notification for another Chef resource to do something.

In your example, it's telling the resource `service[nginx]` to `:reload`. `service[nginx]` is a [`service` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) whose `name` is `nginx`.

For this to work, `service[nginx]` must have been declared in your node's `run_list` at some point. Otherwise, Chef will throw an error. Usually this is either done manually in a recipe by the user, or via a dependency (say, the [`application`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application), or the [`nginx`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nginx) cookbooks).

Exactly how Chef runs the `reload` command depends on how the `service[nginx]` resource was declared, but it usually depends on the underlying operating system (that's one of the beauties of using a tool such as this -- it abstracts many lower level details away from you and allows you to use the same code across multiple platforms).

In the **Syntax** section of the `service` documentation you find this:

- service tells the chef-client to use one of the following providers during the chef-client run: `Chef::Provider::Service::Init`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Debian`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Freebsd`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Gentoo`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Init::Redhat`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Solaris`, `Chef::Provider::Service::Windows`, or `Chef::Provider::Service::Macosx`. The chef-client will detect the platform at the start of the run based on data collected by Ohai. After the platform is identified, the chef-client will determine the correct provider

Comment: You can use `restart_command 'service nginx reload'` too, but I see `provider ...` as less intrusive. Docs: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_service.html

Comment: He need a reload, so `reload_command` should be used instead.

Comment: @sekrett `reload_command` would have to be defined by the `service` provider. It uses `restart_command` to override what the normal operation would be upon `:restart`, so the naming doesn't quite make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality is described in the [chef doco](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#notifications).

If the configuration file's contents change this will trigger a reload of the nginx service. The "delayed" setting means the reload action occurs at the end of the chef run. The idea is that there could be several configuration files changed by a chef run and you want a single reload at the end rather than for each changed file (which is the "immediately" option).